# Create single Exe file from WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to create single `exe` file from my C# WPF project? The project contains some images and videos in Movies folder inside bin.

How can I compile all of this in singe `exe` file? I know it will be large in size but it is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this files to you project and use `Build Action: Resource` for this files. In this case, it will be introduced into the main assembly of application.

It will be a *binary* resource, because it is embedded in the compiled assembly as an opaque binary large object.

Quote from [`Matthew MacDonald book: Pro WPF 4.5 in C#`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430243651):

There are a couple of things that you *must not do* in order to use assembly resources successfully:

- Don’t make the mistake of setting the `Build Action` property to *`Embedded 
  Resource`*. Even though all assembly resources are embedded resources by 
  definition, the Embedded Resource build action places the binary data in another 
  area where it’s more difficult to access. In WPF applications, it’s assumed that you 
  always use a build type of Resource.
- Don’t use the `Resources tab` in the Project Properties window. WPF does not 
  support this type of resource URI.